# Define reference with additional context specific properties

Tags: node.js

in my application I instantiate an application wide object called `controller`. Also I'm starting a server. Since I want to keep redundancy low, on each request I want to instantiate a frontend to `controller`, which is a copy/reference to `controller`, but with an additional `pool` property, which contains request wide objects/configs and can be accessed from inside `controller`.

```
var applicationPool = new ObjectPool(); // container for objects
var controller = new Controller(); // application wide instance
var server = http.createServer();

applicationPool.set("myController", controller);

server.on("request",function(req,res){
    var requestPool = new ObjectPool();

    requestPool.set("request",req);
    requestPool.set("response",res);

    /*
     * pool population
     * routing
     * controller resolving
     * parameter resolving
     */

    // frontend specific to current request
    var frontend = applicationPool.get("myController").create(requestPool);

    // hopefully finishes res
    frontend.greetAction( parameters );

    /*
     * post response actions
     */
}

server.listen(3000);
```

And the `Controller` class:

```
function Controller(){
    BaseController.call(this);
    // ...
}

function greetAction( parameters ){
    var res = this.getObjectPool().get("response"); // defined in BaseController
    res.end(format("Greetings, %s!",parameters["name"]));
}

Controller.prototype = Object.create( BaseController.prototype );
Controller.prototype.greetAction = greetAction;
```

Additional my thoughts about a `BaseController` class:

```
function BaseController(){ ... }

function getObjectPool(){
    return this.pool;
}

function create( pool ){
    var frontend = Object.create( this.__proto__, this );
    frontend.pool = pool;
    return frontend;
}

BaseController.prototype.getObjectPool = getObjectPool;
BaseController.prototype.create = create;
```

This is were I got stuck. For what I tested. If I add `pool` to `frontend` it's also applied to the `controller` object as well. I'm thinking about creating a new object and append all properties of `controller`. I'm also having a glance at proxies, having `controller` as target and a `get` trap for `getObjectPool`.

I know modifying `res` directly is bad practice. I probably will return `string`/`buffer` instead. But the described problem stays. As I plan to embed other controllers.

I'm coming from PHP+Symfony where You have a `Controller` class with a `getContainer` method and shortcuts for core objects, doing the same thing.

Any thoughts are appreciated. Awhile I'm trying to solve this.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got an solution. It's kinda tricky since I'm actually saving all "protected" data in `"__"` property (`this.__.pool`). Here is the code for the working `create` function in this example:

```
function create( pool ){
    return new Proxy(this,{
        get: function(target, property){
            if(property === 'pool') return pool;
            return target[property];
        }
    });
}
```

This returns a Proxy (`frontend`) for `controller`. Everytime I access `pool` of `frontend`, the caller will get redirected to the assigned `pool` argument. Even inside the `frontend` object.

```
//...
var frontend = applicationPool.get("myController").create(requestPool);
frontend.greetAction( parameters ); // this.pool will be redirected to requestPool
//...
```

I will wait for other suggestions, before I check in as resolved.